# How to make an html div to swiftly move to right (for less than 1 second) and disappear?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to make an html div to swiftly move to right (e.g. for less than 1 second) and disappear. Then appear again directly at the position the div was at the very beginning of this process after 1 second. This process will be triggered by a button click and repeat by 10 times.

I tried to use transition-property in CSS to achieve this, but [the result](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FVY2L2VZFUUO) is not what I wanted. The div will directly disappear instead of disappearing after moving to right.

Could it be that what I want to do is impossible to achieve with CSS? If it is the case, what should I use?

The css code:

```
#box1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transition-property: left, right; /* Safari */
    -webkit-transition-duration: 2s; /* Safari */
    transition-property: left, right;
    transition-duration: 2s;
    position:absolute;
    left: 0;
}

#box1:hover {
  transition-delay:1s;
  left: 100px;
  transition-delay:1s;
  opacity:0;
}
```

Javascript code:

```
    var elem = document.getElementById("box1"); 
    $('#b').click(function(){
        var i = 0;
        while (i < 10){

          setTimeout(function(){
            elem.setAttribute("style","left: 1000px;");
          }, 500);
          setTimeout(function(){
            elem.setAttribute("style"," opacity: 0;");
          }, 500);
          i ++;
        }
    })
```

Comment: It isn't impossible in CSS. You'd have to use `keyframes` - but, it can also be done in JS if that's a route you want to take. Either way, can you please post your code so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this in so many ways :

1-using transition and css jQuery method:

```js
//changing the style of the box using css method of jQuery
var animationDuration = 800;
var animationRepetition = 10;
//this array will be used to clear timeouts if user click while animation still going
var timeoutIds = [];
$("#css_method").click(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < timeoutIds.length; i++) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutIds[i]);
  }
  timeoutIds = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < animationRepetition; i++) {
    var index = i;
    var id1 = setTimeout(function() {

      $("#box1").addClass("left-opacity-transition").css({
        left: 500,
        opacity: 0
      });
    }, 2 * index * animationDuration)
    var id2 = setTimeout(function() {

      $("#box1").removeClass("left-opacity-transition").css({
        left: 0,
        opacity: 1
      });
    }, ((2 * index) + 1) * animationDuration);
    timeoutIds.push(id1, id2);
  }
});
```

```css
#box1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}

button {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.left-opacity-transition {
  -webkit-transition-property: left, opacity;
  /* Safari */
  -webkit-transition-duration: .8s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-property: left, opacity;
  transition-duration: .8s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box1"></div>
<button id="css_method" type='button'>use css method</button>
```

2-using animate jQuery method :

```js
//using the animate method of jQuery you can remove the transition from style
var animationDuration = 800;
var animationRepetition = 10;
$("#animate_method").click(function() {
  var $box1 = $("#box1");
  $box1.finish();
  for (var i = 0; i < animationRepetition; i++) {
    $box1.animate({
      left: 500,
      opacity: 0
    }, 800, function() {
      $box1.css({
        left: 0,
        opacity: 1
      });
    });
  }

});
```

```css
#box1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

button {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box1" class="fade-in-left"></div>
<button id="animate_method" type='button'>use animate method</button>
```

3-using translate in a css class :

```js
//using the translateX you also can change the element position in X axis
var animationDuration = 800;
var animationRepetition = 10;
//this array will be used to clear timeouts if user click while animation still going
var timeoutIds = [];
$("#translate_button").click(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < timeoutIds.length; i++) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutIds[i]);
  }
  timeoutIds = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < animationRepetition; i++) {
    var index = i;
    var id1 = setTimeout(function() {
      $("#box1").addClass("transform-opacity-transition translate-fade-left");
    }, 2 * index * animationDuration);
    var id2 = setTimeout(function() {
      $("#box1").removeClass("transform-opacity-transition translate-fade-left");
    }, ((2 * index) + 1) * animationDuration);
    timeoutIds.push(id1, id2);
  }
});
```

```css
#box1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
}

.translate-fade-left {
  transform: translateX(500px);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(500px);
  opacity: 0;
}

.transform-opacity-transition {
  -webkit-transition-property: transform, opacity;
  /* Safari */
  -webkit-transition-duration: .8s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-property: transform, opacity;
  transition-duration: .8s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box1"></div>
<button id="translate_button" type='button'>use translate</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But by "reappearing", I mean reappearing directly at the position the div element original was before the whole process started, instead of the element returning to the original position. (Sorry that I did not express in my question clearly.) Would you mind if you update your answers correspondingly?

Comment: yes sure you will just have to remove transitions when you get the element back to initial position, i did an edit for this and if it is still not the wanted behavior just let me know and i will try to fix it. i do recommend you use the second approach  (2-using animate jQuery method ) because it is browser compatible (doesn't need css transition or transform ) and the animate method is more precise in timing then setTimeout.

Comment: Thank you. Just a suggestion: if it is convenient for you, you might also put the code in the previous version of your answer in a jsfiddle and put the link in your answer for reference purpose.

Comment: @Aqqqq Thank you for the suggestion i will definitely work with your advice, cheers.